# In java how every class is inheriting from Object class without using extends keyword?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

In java how every class is inheriting from Object class without using extends keyword? How can we implement our on java class in the same way?

Comment: Its like that because of a specification. No, you cant implement your own class

Comment: The compiler fills in "extends java.lang.Object` when there is no `extends`. It is written in the .class file. Only the class Object has no super class.

Comment: you should implement your own compiler!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In java how every class is inheriting from Object class without using extends keyword?

By fiat. That is, because the spec says so, in a couple of places (for instance, [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.2)). Probably the clearest is [§8.1.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3):

> Given a (possibly generic) class declaration C<F1,...,Fn> (n ≥ 0, C ≠ Object), the direct superclass of the class type C<F1,...,Fn> is the type given in the extends clause of the declaration of C if an extends clause is present, or Object otherwise.

Continuing with your question:

> How can we implement our on java class in the same way?

You can't.